# Non homogeneous boundary value problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve $$v\frac{dp}{dx}+D\frac{d^2 p}{dx^2}=\delta(x)$$

- boundary conditions: $p(a)=0$, $p'(-b)=0.$

Comment: What are $v$ and $D,$ and what have you tried? The equation is linear, and doesn't even have derivatives w.r.t. $t,$ so I'm thinking it's likely to be separable.

Comment: If you separate out the $x$ and $t$ dependence into $p(x,t)=X(x)\,T(t),$ then $$X(x)=\frac{-\theta (-b) e^{-\frac{a v}{D}}+\theta (a)
    \left(e^{-\frac{a v}{D}}-1\right)+(\theta (-b)-\theta (x)) e^{-\frac{v
    x}{D}}+\theta (x)}{v}, $$ assuming $v$ and $D$ are constants. Here $\theta$ is the Heaviside step function. Because there are literally no constraints on $T(t),$ it could be anything you want.

Comment: v and are constants. p is only function of x. This is ordinary differential equation not partial differential equation

Comment: Then what I've given you there IS the solution.